# Plotly: auto resize height

Tags: python, plotly

I am creating a bar graph using `plotly express` inside `dash` application. The graph is getting displayed but I am having an issue with `height`.Currently I am using `default` height and width.

Now for eg:

1. dataframe having `field` column contain 3 entires, the graph looks ok.
2. dataframe having `field` column contain 10 entires, the bar width is reduced auto and height remains the same and graph looks congested and hard to read.

```
figure = (
    px.bar(
        data_frame=dataframe,
        x="size",
        y="field",
        title="Memory Usage",
        text="size",
        # width=400,
        # height=400,
        orientation="h",
        labels={"size": "size in byte(s)"},
        template=template,
    ).update_traces(width=0.4)
    .update_layout(autosize=True)
)
        
dcc.Graph(id="memory_bar", figure=figure, className="dbc")
```

Is it possible depending on number of entires, the height can be auto-resized? Also I am using `orient` as `horrizontal`. I tried `autosize=true` but got no effect on height it remains same.

Comment: Did you try to adjust the height parameter ? Using a method `f` that returns the height based on the number of entries. It could give something like `height=f(dataframe.shape[0])`.

Comment: Hi ftorre, Thanks. Earlier, I tried setting height to say 600, 800 being static graph sometimes was ok and other times not depending on number of entries. What is `f` and in which package or module it is? passing rows sounds good.

Comment: `f` would be a method that you define and fit your scenario. I posted an answer below that gives an example.

Comment: Hi ftorre, Thanks for detail explanation. I got confused, I thought `f` is some built-in method in `plotly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to define a dynamic width and height based on the dataframe:

- The number of categories can be found with `dataframe['field'].nunique()` (assuming you are using pandas). It will impact the height of the figure (since the bar chart is horizontal)
- The number of entries can be found with `dataframe.shape[0]` and will impact the width of the figure. You could be more precise if you use `dataframe.groupby("field").count()["size"].max()` instead. It returns the maximum entry per category.

Then, we can define two methods for computing height and width of the figure:

```py
def num_fields_based_height(num_fields: int) -> int:
    padding = 150 # arbitrary value depending on legends
    row_size = 100 # arbitrary value
    return padding + row_size * num_fields

def num_entries_based_width(num_entries: int) -> int:
    padding = 150 # arbitrary value depending on legends
    entry_size = 100 # arbitrary value
    return padding + entry_size * num_entries
```

Then call this methods when declaring the figure:

```py
figure = (
    px.bar(
        data_frame=dataframe,
        x="size",
        y="field",
        title="Memory Usage",
        text="size",
        width=num_entries_based_width(dataframe.shape[0]),
        height=num_fields_based_height(dataframe['field'].nunique()),
        orientation="h",
        labels={"size": "size in byte(s)"},
    )
)
```

Now you need to find the right parameters (`padding`, `entry_size`, `row_size`) for your scenario.